# Proxy settings not working for HERE Verify Credentials Tutorial

Tags: here-olp

I am having some trouble autheticaiting my credentials with here using a  proxy behind a corporate firewall.  My proxy settings work fine for maven, but cant seem to connect to HERE. I just get a bunch of ailure(akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Connection failed.)) messages.  Can anyone tell me why this isnt working and what I can do to fix it?

https://developer.here.com/olp/documentation/olp-developer-tutorials/dev_guide/verify-credentials/index.html

```
$ mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=CatalogInfoJava -Dhttp.proxyHost=[internet.blah.com] -Dhttp.proxyPort=[83] -Dexec.mainClass=CatalogInfoJava -Dhttps.proxyHost=[internet.blah.com] -Dhttps.proxyPort=[83]
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from HERE_PLATFORM_REPO: https://repo.platform.here.com/artifactory/open-location-platform/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from HERE_PLATFORM_REPO: https://repo.platform.here.com/artifactory/open-location-platform/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to HERE_PLATFORM_REPO (https://repo.platform.here.com/artifactory/open-location-platform): [internet.ford.com]
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to HERE_PLATFORM_REPO (https://repo.platform.here.com/artifactory/open-location-platform): [internet.ford.com]
Downloading from HERE_PLATFORM_REPO: https://repo.platform.here.com/artifactory/open-location-platform/org/codehaus/mojo/exec-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to HERE_PLATFORM_REPO (https://repo.platform.here.com/artifactory/open-location-platform): [internet.ford.com]
[INFO]
[INFO] -----------< com.here.platform.tutorial:verify-credentials >------------
[INFO] Building Verify Platform Credentials Tutorial 0.2.171
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from https://repo.platform.here.com/artifactory/open-location-platform was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of HERE_PLATFORM_REPO has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to HERE_PLATFORM_REPO (https://repo.platform.here.com/artifactory/open-location-platform): [internet.ford.com]
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from https://repo.platform.here.com/artifactory/open-location-platform was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of HERE_PLATFORM_REPO has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to HERE_PLATFORM_REPO (https://repo.platform.here.com/artifactory/open-location-platform): [internet.ford.com]
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from https://repo.platform.here.com/artifactory/open-location-platform was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of HERE_PLATFORM_REPO has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to HERE_PLATFORM_REPO (https://repo.platform.here.com/artifactory/open-location-platform): [internet.ford.com]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ verify-credentials ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ verify-credentials ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- scala-maven-plugin:4.1.0:compile (default) @ verify-credentials ---
[INFO] Using incremental compilation using Mixed compile order
[INFO] compile in 1.6 s
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) @ verify-credentials ---
[INFO] [10/17/2019 11:16:21.050] [CatalogInfoJava.main()] [DataClientSettingsExt] Reading credentials from default credentials file C:\Users\RJONE646\.here\credentials.properties
[INFO] [10/17/2019 11:16:21.708] [CatalogInfoJava.main()] [DataClientSettingsExt] duration timeouts.durable-write-volume-overall is not defined)
[INFO] [10/17/2019 11:16:21.709] [CatalogInfoJava.main()] [DataClient$] Constructed a Data Client of version=0.3.36
[INFO] [10/17/2019 11:16:22.113] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [OAuthHereTokenRequester] Retry #1 for refresh HERE Token (previous result: Failure(akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Connection failed.)) in 0 ms...
[INFO] [10/17/2019 11:16:22.119] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [OAuthHereTokenRequester] Retry #2 for refresh HERE Token (previous result: Failure(akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Connection failed.)) in 374 ms...
[INFO] [10/17/2019 11:16:22.516] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [OAuthHereTokenRequester] Retry #3 for refresh HERE Token (previous result: Failure(akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Connection failed.)) in 738 ms...
[INFO] [10/17/2019 11:16:23.278] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [OAuthHereTokenRequester] Retry #4 for refresh HERE Token (previous result: Failure(akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Connection failed.)) in 1501 ms...
[INFO] [10/17/2019 11:16:24.804] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [OAuthHereTokenRequester] Retry #5 for refresh HERE Token (previous result: Failure(akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Connection failed.)) in 3024 ms...
[INFO] [10/17/2019 11:16:27.864] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12] [OAuthHereTokenRequester] Retry #6 for refresh HERE Token (previous result: Failure(akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Connection failed.)) in 6063 ms...
[INFO] [10/17/2019 11:16:33.957] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12] [OAuthHereTokenRequester] Retry #7 for refresh HERE Token (previous result: Failure(akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Connection failed.)) in 12166 ms...
[INFO] [10/17/2019 11:16:46.149] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [OAuthHereTokenRequester] Retry #8 for refresh HERE Token (previous result: Failure(akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Connection failed.)) in 24368 ms...
[INFO] [10/17/2019 11:17:10.540] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [OAuthHereTokenRequester] Retry #9 for refresh HERE Token (previous result: Failure(akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Connection failed.)) in 29977 ms...
[INFO] [10/17/2019 11:17:40.547] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [OAuthHereTokenRequester] Retry #10 for refresh HERE Token (previous result: Failure(akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Connection failed.)) in 29970 ms...
[INFO] [10/17/2019 11:18:10.548] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [OAuthHereTokenRequester] Retry #11 for refresh HERE Token (previous result: Failure(akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Connection failed.)) in 29969 ms...
[INFO] [10/17/2019 11:18:40.541] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [OAuthHereTokenRequester] Retry #12 for refresh HERE Token (previous result: Failure(akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Connection failed.)) in 29976 ms...
[INFO] [10/17/2019 11:19:10.549] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [OAuthHereTokenRequester] Retry #13 for refresh HERE Token (previous result: Failure(akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Connection failed.)) in 29968 ms...
[INFO] [10/17/2019 11:19:40.554] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [OAuthHereTokenRequester] Retry #14 for refresh HERE Token (previous result: Failure(akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Connection failed.)) in 29963 ms...
[INFO] [10/17/2019 11:20:10.555] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [OAuthHereTokenRequester] Retry #15 for refresh HERE Token (previous result: Failure(akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Connection failed.)) in 29961 ms...
[INFO] [10/17/2019 11:20:40.549] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [OAuthHereTokenRequester] Retry #16 for refresh HERE Token (previous result: Failure(akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Connection failed.)) in 29967 ms...
[INFO] [10/17/2019 11:21:10.550] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12] [OAuthHereTokenRequester] Retry #17 for refresh HERE Token (previous result: Failure(akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Connection failed.)) in 29966 ms...
[INFO] [10/17/2019 11:21:40.537] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [OAuthHereTokenRequester] Retry #18 for refresh HERE Token (previous result: Failure(akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Connection failed.)) in 29979 ms...
[INFO] [10/17/2019 11:22:10.537] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [OAuthHereTokenRequester] Retry #19 for refresh HERE Token (previous result: Failure(akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Connection failed.)) in 29979 ms...
[INFO] [10/17/2019 11:22:40.544] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12] [OAuthHereTokenRequester] Retry #20 for refresh HERE Token (previous result: Failure(akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Connection failed.)) in 29972 ms...
[INFO] [10/17/2019 11:23:10.547] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [OAuthHereTokenRequester] Retry #21 for refresh HERE Token (previous result: Failure(akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Connection failed.)) in 29969 ms...
[INFO] [10/17/2019 11:23:40.553] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-29] [OAuthHereTokenRequester] Retry #22 for refresh HERE Token (previous result: Failure(akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Connection failed.)) in 29964 ms...
[INFO] [10/17/2019 11:24:10.539] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-29] [OAuthHereTokenRequester] Retry #23 for refresh HERE Token (previous result: Failure(akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Connection failed.)) in 29977 ms...
[INFO] [10/17/2019 11:24:40.552] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12] [OAuthHereTokenRequester] Retry #24 for refresh HERE Token (previous result: Failure(akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Connection failed.)) in 29964 ms...
[INFO] [10/17/2019 11:25:10.548] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [OAuthHereTokenRequester] Retry #25 for refresh HERE Token (previous result: Failure(akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Connection failed.)) in 29968 ms...
[INFO] [10/17/2019 11:25:40.546] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-29] [OAuthHereTokenRequester] Retry #26 for refresh HERE Token (previous result: Failure(akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Connection failed.)) in 29970 ms...
[INFO] [10/17/2019 11:26:10.546] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [OAuthHereTokenRequester] Retry #27 for refresh HERE Token (previous result: Failure(akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Connection failed.)) in 29969 ms...
[INFO] [10/17/2019 11:26:40.548] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [OAuthHereTokenRequester] Retry #28 for refresh HERE Token (previous result: Failure(akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Connection failed.)) in 29968 ms...
```

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using Data Client Library, so did you also configure the proxy settings in your application.conf file? [How to configure proxy for Data Client Library](https://developer.here.com/olp/documentation/data-client-library/dev_guide/client/proxy-setup.html#configuration-property-file)